# Linux routing: How to allow a device inside private network to connect a public IP over an unknown network?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, nat, linux-networking

Consider following network topology:

```
                            ----------
    ---- (my network) ---- | Device 1 | (.101)
   |  192.168.191.0/24 |    ----------
   |                   |      ----------
   |                    ---- | Device 2 | (.102)
   |                   |      ----------
   |                   |         ----------
   |                    ------- | Device 3 | (.103)
   |                             ----------  .
  eth1 (.1)                                    . . . . . . . . .
   |                                                             .
  --------                                 ---                  ------------
 | Router | eth0 --- (unknown network) -- | ? | -- Internet -- | D3 Servers |
  --------                                 ---                  ------------
```

I have a linux router between my private network and an unknown network. The unknown network  can be another private network, I do not have control over that at all.

Most of the devices in my internal network connect the outside world over an HTTP Proxy residing in the Router, so there is no need for NAT between the private network and the unknown network.

However, I have one device (Device 3) that should be able to connect to a set of **public IP** address directly.

Because the unknown network can be also a private network, NATting might not be an option (due double NAT). Device 3 needs to connect a set of known public IP addresses and ports that cannot be changed. Device 3 can be isolated to another network logically (with DHCP configuration from the Router) but not physically. Apparently Device 3 cannot utilize the HTTP Proxy (CONNECT) provided by the Router.

**Can I somehow configure my router to allow Device 3 to connect any public IP, and if yes, how?**

Comment: Did you try NAT and encountered some issues?

Comment: @dusan.bajic, yes I did - NAT works fine if the unknown network is public one, but in case it's private packets get lost. Most likely due the double NAT.

Comment: I think it is unlikely that double NAT is the reason. Did you try on several different private networks?

Comment: I have tested NAT in two different networks yet and in both case the public addresses cannot be connected. I cannot, however, ensure it's due NAT (can be a firewall issue too).

Comment: Currently, the devices in your network can connect to the unknown network without nat, right? Somewhere between your network and the internet NAT should occur in order for you to be able to connect to the internet from your network. Do you currently have access to the internet from your network? If no, how about from your router?